# Silverstripe system using another Silverstripe system as Login Authorisation

Tags: authentication, authorization, silverstripe

I'm aware of various authentication modules for [OPAuth](https://github.com/BetterBrief/silverstripe-opauth), [OAuth](https://github.com/bigfork/silverstripe-oauth-login), [LDAP](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-activedirectory) and [OpenID](https://github.com/oddnoc/silverstripe-auth_openid) for using other systems as login authentication.

My question is which method works to setup authorisation for silverstripe systems from another silverstripe system... so that the users can be solely managed from one installation.  All installations are under full control.

I am ***not*** talking about [subsites](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-subsites)... these systems are completely separate - different servers, databases, etc.

Use Case...

AuthSite is the single auth site setup and ClientSiteA and ClientSiteB are both using AuthSite.  A User is registered in AuthSite with access to ClientSiteA - this user then can log into ClientSiteA, but not ClientSiteB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the systems you listed will work, however you'll need to code it yourself.

If they're on the same server and you're looking for the quick and dirty solution, I'd probably suggest overriding `MemberAuthenticator` to use AuthSite's database.

More eloquently, you'd probably want to create some sort of authentication interface on AuthSite which is used by `MemberAuthenticator`on ClientSiteA and ClientSiteB. This allows ClientSiteA and ClientSiteB to be hosted elsewhere without having to muck with database settings.